# Add full blown annotation view with driving directions using Mapkit and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotationview

I am using the the following code to create an annotation pin on a map.  When selected, it shows the name of the `MKMapItem` such as McDonald's.  However, I would like it to show a full blown annotation with more detail including address, picture if available and driving directions.  The tutorials I've seen seen on [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2765-overlay-images-and-overlay-views-with-mapkit-tutorial) and elsewhere go further than I need in terms of introducing custom artwork, a custom class and so forth.  I just the basics and a button for driving directions.

How would I expand the following to show more detail and a button for driving directions?

```
mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
let location : CLLocationCoordinate2D = self.aRestaurant.placemark.coordinate

let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = location
annotation.title = self.aRestaurant.placemark.name
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `MKAnnotationView` set the property

```
self.detailCalloutAccessoryView = calloutView
```

`calloutView` can be any subclass of `UIView` with subViews including UIButtons for some user interaction.

`calloutView` replaces the subtitle. The title will still be visible.

For simple cases you can add

```
leftCalloutAccessoryView = myButton1
rightCalloutAccessoryView = myButton2
```

For buttons that are displayed on the left and right side of the center view.

If you use `MKMarkerAnnotationView`s, you also get the title and subtitle for free below the markerView on the map, so that the user sees the title + subtitle without opening the AnnotationView.